# Return appointment "all day" in Lotus Domino calendar (version 8.5.1)

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have an appointment "all day" in Lotus Domino calendar (version 8.5.1) that is planned from 02/23/2017 to 03/01/2017. I use NCSO.jar and I try to get this appointment from Lotus Domino in this manner:

```
lotus.domino.Session s = null;
s = DominoSessionInfo.sessionInfo.getSession();
lotus.domino.Database maildb = getMailDb(sessionInfo);
lotus.domino.DateRange dr = s.createDateRange(startDate, endDate);
lotus.domino.View calview = maildb.getView("($Calendar)");
lotus.domino.ViewEntryCollection docColl = calview.getAllEntriesByKey(dr);
```

with

```
public static lotus.domino.Database getMailDb(DominoSessionInfo sessionInfo) throws NotesException, NamingException{

lotus.domino.Session s = DominoSessionInfo.sessionInfo.getSession();
log.info("Open DB on: " + s.getServerName() + " with mail server *" +
        sessionInfo.getProfileInfo().getMailServer() + "* and mail file *" +
        sessionInfo.getProfileInfo().getMailFile());
    lotus.domino.Database maildb = s.getDatabase(sessionInfo.getProfileInfo().getMailServer(),
        sessionInfo.getProfileInfo().getMailFile());
if (! maildb.isOpen()){
    maildb.open();
}
return maildb;
}
```

When dr.getText(): 02/27/2017 12:00:00 AM CET - 03/06/2017 12:00:00 AM CET (i.e. startDate: 02/27/2017 12:00:00 AM CET and endDate: 03/06/2017 12:00:00 AM CET) this code doesn't return this appointment while when dr.getText(): 02/20/2017 12:00:00 AM CET - 02/27/2017 12:00:00 AM CET (i.e. startDate: 02/20/2017 12:00:00 AM CET and endDate: 02/27/2017 12:00:00 AM CET) this code returns this appointment.

How can I modify the code in order to return this appointment when the value of startDate and endDate are, respectively, 02/27/2017 12:00:00 AM CET and 03/06/2017 12:00:00 AM CET?

Thanks in advance.

Image: [Appointment Lotus Notes screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49jkX.jpg)

Comment: Have you looked at the values in the CalendarDateTime item in the appointment document and checked what the time component is?

Comment: Hi Richard, the value of CalendarDateTime item in the appointment is the following; doc.getItemValue("CalendarDateTime"): [02/23/2017 12:00:00 AM CET]

Comment: There is only one value in CalendarDateTime? There is not a list showing every day from 2/23 to 3/1?

Comment: Yes, there's only one value in CalendarDateTime because it isn't a recurrent appointment; it's only one appointment 'all-day' planned from 02/23/2017 12:00:00 AM CET (date start) to 03/01/2017 12:00:00 AM CET (date end)

Comment: I. I got the wrong impression because you said "appointment" instead of "appointments!". So what are the time values in your startDate and endDate variables? Or more importantly, what are the time values if you look at dr.getStartDateTime() and dr.getEndDateTime()?

Comment: I've a service with 2 dates input (start,end) to returns appointments from Lotus Domino
1.When parameters value (02/20/2017,02/27/2017), the appointment is returned and:
dr.getStartDateTime():02/20/2017 12:00:00 AM CET
dr.getEndDateTime(): 02/27/2017 12:00:00 AM CET
2. When parameters value (02/27/2017,03/06/2017), the appointment isn't returned and:
dr.getStartDateTime():02/27/2017 12:00:00 AM CET
dr.getEndDateTime(): 03/06/2017 12:00:00 AM CET
I would expect that in the second case the appointment is returned because I have it in the first three day (02/27/2017,02/28/2017,03/01/2017)

Comment: Well, this old blog post (http://avatar.red-pill.mobi/nathan/escape.nsf//d6plinks/NTFN-79TMQF) implies that it ought to work. I'm not sure why it's giving you a problem. Calendar views are a bit strange. Can you create a flat view that selects the calendar docs and try getting them from there?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to resolve this problem! Instead of this code:

```
lotus.domino.DateRange dr = s.createDateRange(startDate, endDate);
lotus.domino.View calview = maildb.getView("($Calendar)");
lotus.domino.ViewEntryCollection docColl = calview.getAllEntriesByKey(dr);
```

I used this:

```
String strDateFormat;
// Get the date separator used on the Domino server, e.g. / or -
String dateSep = s.getInternational().getDateSep();
// Determine if the server date format is DMY, YMD, or MDY
if (s.getInternational().isDateDMY()) {
    strDateFormat = "dd" + dateSep + "MM" + dateSep + "yyyy";                
}
else if (s.getInternational().isDateYMD()) {
   strDateFormat = "yyyy" + dateSep + "MM" + dateSep + "dd";
}
else {
    strDateFormat = "MM" + dateSep + "dd" + dateSep + "yyyy";
}
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);

String calendarQuery = "SELECT (@IsAvailable(CalendarDateTime) & @IsAvailable(EndDateTime) & (@Explode(CalendarDateTime) *<= @Explode(@TextToTime(\"" + dateFormat.format(endDate) + "\")))  (@Explode(EndDateTime) *>= @Explode(@TextToTime(\"" + dateFormat.format(startDate) + "\"))))";

lotus.domino.DocumentCollection queryResults = maildb.search(calendarQuery);
```

Doing so I was able to return the appointment "all-day" (planned from 02/23/2017 to 03/01/2017) for any time interval that contains at least one day in which the appointment is planned.